# Can we read http reponse from flutter WebBrowser?

Tags: flutter, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am looking for getting a token from an Azure Active Directory in a Flutter app.

To do so I was thinking of launch an in-app browser to handle all the authentication part.

So here is my question : Can the in-app browser returns me the HTTP response that he received ?

Here is the link to the flutter package I was thinking of : [link](https://pub.dev/packages/web_browser)

Many thanks in advance for any of your answer !

Comment: Did you check https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth ? I use this to request a code from a webview and then store the tokens.

Comment: @VincentDR I have already used it, but it gives me a compact token at the end, when I try to use it in an API for exemple, this kind of token isn't recognized...

Comment: What kind of auth you are using? The request code one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)?  You need to exchange this code to the two tokens.

Comment: @VincentDR I'm using the access token, aad_oauth gives me after the Id Token but it's not enough to authenticate a user through the API after

Comment: @VincentDR finally I've found the reason why the token never works, it's because the token received contains escape caracters and aren't handled on the next steps, I'll post a need question about this